# Is the tangent bundle the DISJOINT union of tangent spaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and consider the Lee's definition of the tangent space $T_pM$ (so $T_pM$ is the vector space of derivations at $p$). The canonical definition of tangent bundle (as set) of $M$ is: 
$$TM=\bigcup_{p\in M}\{ p\}\times T_pM$$
so it is the disjoint union of all tangent spaces; but L.W.Tu in his "Introduction to Manifolds" says that the tangent spaces are already disjoint and for this reason he defines
$$TM=\bigcup_{p\in M} T_pM$$

Why we can't find a common derivation between $T_pM$ and $T_qM$ if $q\neq p$? I think that Tu's statement  is not true.

Comment: How did Lee and Tu respectively define $T_pM$?

Comment: This should also be differential-topology, not differential-geometry.

Comment: I just noticed this question. I'll add that with the definition of $T_pM$ that I give in my book (derivations of $C^\infty(M)$ at $p$), the zero derivation is a derivation at $p$ for every $p$, so defining the tangent bundle as a simple union would not work. I understand the advantages of defining $T_pM$ as the set of derivations of the space of germs (and I often think of it that way myself), but for pedagogical reasons I made the decision to use the conceptually simpler definition involving $C^\infty(M)$, which I thought would be a little easier for novices to wrap their heads around.

Comment: @JackLee https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982860/why-are-c-infty-p-neq-c-infty-q-when-p-neq-q

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A derivation at $p\in M$ is in particular a linear  map $\partial: C^\infty_p \to \mathbb R$ defined on the set of germs of smooth functions at $p$,  and similarly for $q$.
So the sets of derivations at $p$ and $q$ are disjoint simply because they consist of maps with different domains (namely  $C^\infty_p$ and $C^\infty_q$).   And maps with different domains cannot be equal, as follows from the set-theoretical definition  of  "map".

Comment: Tu's definition of derivation is different from that in Lee's book. The first, uses germs instead the latter says that a derivation is a linear function with domain $C ^{\infty} (M)$

Comment: As an algebraic/analytic geometer I much prefer the definition with germs. The other definition works in differential geometry because of the specific result that the canonical map $\mathcal C^\infty(M) \to \mathcal C^\infty_p$ is surjective. This is completely false in the algebraic/analytic category.

Comment: But how are we sure that we always have $C^\infty_p \neq C^\infty_q$ for $q\neq p$?

Comment: in a hausdorff space p and q are separated by open neighborhoods which i suspect make up the domains of the elements of $C_p^\infty$ and $C_q^\infty$.

Comment: Here is the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982860/why-are-c-infty-p-neq-c-infty-q-when-p-neq-q