# Disjointness of derivations at different points in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I know that in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ a derivation at a point $a$ is a linear map $w \, \colon C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the product rule
$$w(fg) = f(a)wg + g(a)wf.$$
One then defines the tangent space to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ at $a$ to be the set $T_{a}\mathbb{R}^{n}$ of all derivations at $a$. It turns out that such set is a vector space isomorphic to the so-called geometric tangent space $\mathbb{R}^{n}_{a} = \{a\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Here is where my confusion starts: with the above definition, I am not able to spot, given a geometric tangent vector $v_{a}$ at $a$, a tangent vector at $b \neq a$ which corresponds to the same derivation as $v_{a}$. Are $T_{a}\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $T_{b}\mathbb{R}^{n}$ disjoint?

Comment: You should be more explicit about what you are denoting by $C^\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the tangent spaces at different points are disjoint.  Using the linear structure of the vector space we identify them when convenient. Moreover when the base manifold is Euclidean space itself, such an identification can be described as *natural* or *canonical*.  However when the base manifold if a more general space there is no natural way of identifying tangent spaces at distinct points.  This is where the theory of connections starts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Then why do we need to define the tangent bundle as the _disjoint_ union of tangent spaces?

Comment: Well the individual tangent spaces are automatically disjoint, as I mentioned in my answer.  I am not sure which book you are working with but I imagine the author added "disjoint" precisely because students tend to expect that the spaces will be identified, as they are in highschool (by "moving the initial point of the vector to the origin").

Comment: I am using Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. I got confused because [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228840/is-the-tangent-bundle-the-disjoint-union-of-tangent-spaces) seems to point out that, using Lee's definition of derivation (as opposed to Tu's), one needs to define the tangent bundle using the disjoint union

Comment: If you interpret $C^\infty$ as literally the space of smooth functions on the manifold (rather than talking about germs, etc.) then you get unwanted overlaps; for example the identically zero derivation is the origin in all of the tangent spaces. It must be for this reason that Lee introduces the additional parameter $p$ in his definition. That's why I asked you what you mean exactly by $C^\infty$ above.

Comment: Yes I wrote $C^{\infty}$ while I wanted $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Mikhail, why is it that the set of germs at different points are disjoint?