# Why are $C^\infty_p\neq C^\infty_q$ when $p\neq q$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $C^\infty_p(M)$ be the set of all germs at point $p \in M$.

A *germ* at point $x$ is $$[f]_x = \{ g \in C^{\infty} (\mathcal{U}_x) :(\exists \mathcal{O_x} \subset \mathcal{U}_x) (g|_{\mathcal{O_x}}=f) \} \ ,$$ where $\mathcal{U}_x$ and $\mathcal{O_x}$ are open neighbourhoods of $x$, in $M$.

Why do we always have $C^\infty_p\neq C^\infty_q$ when $p\neq q$?

I need to understand this in order to understand how the tangent spaces 'as the' set of derivations are always disjoint for different points.

Comment: They are isomorphic to one another, of course, but there are many different isomorphisms. Hence, given $f\in C^\infty_p$ and $g\in C^\infty_q$, there is no way to determine whether $f=g$ or not.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Thanks for your comment. So, you're saying that whenever there are 2 or more different isomorphisms, since there is no way to determine whether g=f, we just say that both sets are different?

Comment: You want to prove $C^\infty_p\cap C^\infty_q=\emptyset$, not just $C^\infty_p\neq C^\infty_q$ - right?

Comment: Please answer for the sake of clarity: what exactly are $f$, $\mathcal{U}_x$ and $C^{\infty}(\mathcal{U}_x)$? By your definition, are $f$ and $\mathcal{U}_x$ *fixed* when defining the germ $[f]_x$? This is what is written, being quite strict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A smooth germ at $p$ is an equivalence class of pairs $(U,f)$ consisting of an open neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ and a smooth function $f$ on $U$, modulo the equivalence relation that $(U,f) \sim (V,g)$ if there is an open neighbourhood $W$ of $p$, $W \subset U \cap V$, such that $f|_W = g|_W$. We denote the collection of all smooth germs at $p$ by $C_p^\infty$.

If $p \neq q$, no germ at $q$ can belong to the set of germs at $p$. For, suppose $f \in C_q^\infty \cap C_p^\infty$. Let $(U_1,g_1)$ be a representative of the equivalence class of $f$ in $C_p^\infty$, and let $(U_2,g_2)$ be a representative of the equivalence class of $f$ in $C_q^\infty$. We can always choose the open neighbourhoods $U_1$ and $U_2$ (of $p$ and $q$, respectively) in such a manner that $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$, since $\Bbb{R}^n$ is Hausdorff.
Now, since $g_1$ and $g_2$ are both representatives of $f$, it must be that they agree on an open set $V \subset U_1 \cap U_2$, where $V$ is an open neighbourhood of both $p$ and $q$. But, this is not possible since $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$.

Hence, $C_p^\infty$ and $C_q^\infty$ are completely distinct when $p \neq q$.

---

*Edit (based on comments for further clarification):*

> I was rereading your answer, and I have a doubt. In the 2nd paragraph, why is there such a $V$? The representatives of f are representatives, but at different points... ;)
>
> Brahadeesh, I've added the definition I'm using of germ. With that definition, I fail to see how we can guarantee the existence of such a V.

The same (or similar) reasoning goes through with the definition of germ that you updated in the question details. Suppose $[f_x]=[f_y]$ for some $x \neq y$, as per your definition. Then, they have the same set of representatives. Let $U_x$ and $U_y$ be disjoint open neighbourhoods of $x$ and $y$, respectively. Choose $g \in C^\infty(U_x)$ to be a representative of $[f_x]$, so that there exists $O_x \subset U_x$ with $g|_{O_x} = f$. Since $[f_x]=[f_y]$, $g$ is also a representative of $[f_y]$, which is absurd.

At this point, it depends on what you want to say: it is absurd because $y \not\in U_x$ itself, so you are done. But if it’s not immediately clear with this, you could proceed a little bit ahead with the absurdity and observe it happen at another point, as I did previously in my answer. So, let $h \in C^\infty(U_y)$ be a representative of $[f_y]$. Since $[f_x]=[f_y]$, we now have two representatives of $[f_x]$. Hence there is a third representative $k \in C^\infty(U)$ of $[f_x]$ such that $U \subset U_x \cap U_y$. But this is absurd because $U_x \cap U_y = \emptyset$.

> Also, if your reasoning was correct, then how come, in Arthur's answer, we can find a common function at germs in different points?

A germ at a point is not just a smooth function with *(some conditions)*, it is an equivalence class of pairs of smooth functions and neighbourhoods of that point satisfying *(some conditions)*. Arthur does not say in his answer that we can find a common germ, so there is no contradiction.

Comment: You meant $W \ni p$ ? Otherwise I don't see what you mean. If you meant $p \in W$ then (thanks to $C^\infty_c$) we can find a smooth function agreeing with $f$ around $p$ but disagreeing with $g$ at $q$, even if $f,g$ agree on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus for analytic functions we have a different situation.

Comment: @reuns I don't follow. What is $W$? And how do compactly supported functions come into the picture?

Comment: Without asking that a fixed $p \in W$ then it is not an equivalence relation (not transitive) : we can find $f$ agreeing with $g$ somewhere and with $h$ elsewhere but $g$ doesn't agree with $h$ anywhere

Comment: @reuns I still don't follow. Neither the OP nor I have used the notation $W$, so I'm not sure what you mean. And you said "(thanks to $C_c^\infty$)" in your previous comment, which I also do not follow.

Comment: $(f,U) \sim (g,V)$ if $f = g$ on some open $W \subset U \cap V$. I'm saying the definition for it to be an equivalence relation on smooth functions is that $(f,U \ni p) \sim (g,V \ni p)$ if $f = g$ on some open $W \subset U \cap V$ containing $p$. With analytic functions we don't need the restriction $p \in W$, the difference being that $C^\infty$ contains $C^\infty_c$ (ie. the restriction to a smaller open isn't injective)

Comment: @reuns Turns out I'm selectively blind, sorry about that. >.< Yes, I agree with you. And that is what I was trying to say in this answer, but it happened in a roundabout fashion. If it's completely unclear, I can try to rewrite the answer, or delete it, as appropriate. Your suggestion?

Comment: I just wanted you to state clearly that $p \in W$, not to delete the answer :)

Comment: @reuns Added that $p \in W$ :) Thanks for the clarification. I didn't know that the situation for analytic functions is so different, by the way. Thanks for that too, I learnt something new.

Comment: Much obliged Brahadeesh ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. My pleasure :)

Comment: I was rereading your answer, and I have a doubt. In the 2nd paragraph, why is there such a $V$? The representatives of f are representatives, but at different points... ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. We are assuming that $f$ is a germ at $p$ as well as $q$ to arrive at a contradiction. Since $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, if there were such an $f$ then there ought to exist such a $V$ as in para 2 too. If it’s clear that no such $V$ exists then this answer is really much ado about nothing.

Comment: Brahadeesh, I've added the definition I'm using of germ. With that definition, I fail to see how we can guarantee the existence of such a V.

Comment: Also, if your reasoning was correct, then how come, in Arthur's answer, we can find a common function at germs in different points?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I'm really not sure what's unclear, but here goes: suppose $[f_x] = [f_y]$ for some $x \neq y$, as per your definition. Then, they have the same set of representatives. Let $U_x$ and $U_y$ be disjoint open neighbourhoods of $x$ and $y$, respectively. Choose $g \in C^{\infty}(\mathcal{U}_x)$ to be a representative of $[f_x]$, so that there exists $O_x \subset U_x$ with $g|_{O_x} = f$. Since $[f_x] = [f_y]$, $g$ is also a representative of $[f_y]$, which is absurd.

Comment: At this point, it depends on what you want to say: it is absurd because $y \not\in U_x$ itself, so you are done. But if it’s not immediately clear with this, you could proceed a little bit ahead with the absurdity and observe it happen at another point, like in my answer. So, let $h \in C^{\infty}(U_y)$ be a representative of $[f_y]$. Since $[f_x] = [f_y]$, we now have two representatives of $[f_x]$. Hence there is a third representative $k \in C^{\infty}(U)$ of $[f_x]$ such that $U \subset U_x \cap U_y$. But this is absurd because $U_x \cap U_y = \emptyset$.

Comment: A germ at a point is not just a smooth function with *<some conditions>*, it is an equivalence class of pairs of smooth functions and neighbourhoods of that point satisfying *<some conditions>*. Arthur does not say in his answer that we can find a common germ, so there is no contradiction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89205/discussion-between-brahadeesh-and-an-old-man-in-the-sea).

Comment: @user279515 please answer for the sake of clarity: in your definition of smooth germs at $p$, the relation $\sim$ you defined is an relation with respect to what set? Because I am in doubt it is really an equivalence relation the way it is written.

Answer (score 1):

They are isomorphic as $\Bbb R$ vector spaces (or algebras, for that matter), but completely distinct. They are both partitions of $C^\infty(\Bbb R)$ into equivalence classes (or something closely analogous, depending on your exact definition of "germ"), but those two partitions have little to do with one another.

For instance, given any two germs $\alpha\in C^\infty_p(\Bbb R^n)$ and $\beta\in C^\infty_q(\Bbb R^n)$, there is an $f\in C^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$ which is contained in both $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Arthur, thanks for your answer. However, I'm not seeing how from the existence of a 'thinner' partition, we conclude both are very distinct...

Comment: @Anopdmaninthesea. What "thinner partition"? I'm just giving an example of how independent the two partitions are of one another.

Comment: Arthur, can you give me an example of an element/germ in set, but not the other?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea The two sets have no elements at all in common. Every single element / germ in one is not in the other.

Comment: Ahhh, so, in any germ at point $p$, we can find an $f$ which is $C^{\infty}$ at an open neighbourhood of $p$, but it's not $C^{\infty}$ at an open neighbourhood of $q$, or it may not even be defined $q$. Or even if define in a way that all the previous are satisfied, we still  have $[f_1]_p=[f_2]_p$ but $[f_1]_q\neq [f_2]_q$,.  Ex: $f_1=f_2=0$ at $\mathcal{O_p}$, but $f_1=0$ at $\mathcal{O_p}$ and  $f_2=x^2-q^2$ at $\mathcal{O_q}$. Correct?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. The functions have to be defined and $C^{\infty}$ everywhere, so your first sentences will not work. But your last sentence about $[f_1]_p = [f_2]_p$ but $[f_1]_q\neq [f_2]_q$ is essentially it, yes. Given any $g\in C^{\infty}$, the sets $[g]_p$ and $[g]_q$ are necessarily distinct. Even more generally, given any $g_1, g_2\in C^\infty$, $[g_1]_p$ and $[g_2]_q$ cannot be the same sets of $C^{\infty} functions.