# Domain of pushforward

Tags: notation, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, pushforward

In these [lecture notes on Lie algebras](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/classical/classical14.pdf) they give a definition of the pushforward that I haven't seen before.

$$\psi_* = d\psi_x: T_xX → T_{\psi(x)}N$$

I understand $d\psi_x$, but $\psi_*$ makes no mention of which point it is attached to, so I wouldn't be able to guess its intended domain. Given a $\psi: X \to N$, its pushforward is well-defined on *all* the tangent spaces of $X$, I think.

We are soon asked to check that:

$$(1_X)_∗ = 1_{T_xX}$$

Again, this check only makes sense if I can compare their domains, but the object on the left doesn't reference a point. Why not? Of course, if I restrict the pushforward on the left to the space $T_xX$ I can confirm their equality, but that doesn't seem to be what this notation is suggesting.

Comment: It's a typo I think. If $Y$ is a vector field on $X$, then since $\psi $ is a diffeomorphism, $\psi_*$ is defined unambiguously by  $(\psi_*Y)_q=d\psi_{\psi^{-1}(q)}(Y_{\psi^{-1}(q))})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often, people usually just infer the domain when the point isn't explicitly mention it. But really, there are several ways of formulating the concept of push-forward. The first is point by point, and then extending to the whole tangent bundle, and the second is to define it on the entire tangent bundle, and then define it at a point via restriction.

Let $X,N$ be smooth manifolds and $\psi:X \to N$ be a smooth map.

---

**First Approach:** (Pointwise to globally)

Then, for each point $x\in X$, we can define the **pushforward of $\psi$ at $x$** to be the map $\psi_{*x}: T_xX \to T_{\psi(x)}N$ defined by
\begin{align}
\psi_{*x} \big([\gamma]\big) := [\psi \circ \gamma]
\end{align}

So, here we started by defining the pushforward at a point. We can extend this to the entire tangent bundle very easily, because given an equivalence class of curves $[\gamma] \in TX$, since the tangent spaces are all disjoint, we know that **there exists a unique** $x\in X$ such that $[\gamma] \in T_xX$ (in fact $x = \gamma(0)$). So, with this observation, we can define $\psi_* : TX \to TN$ as
\begin{align}
\psi_* \big( [\gamma]\big) &:= \psi_{*x} \big( [\gamma] \big) \quad \text{where $x$ is the unique point of $X$ such that $[\gamma] \in T_xX$}
\end{align}

---

**Second Approach:** (Globally to pointwise)

(For some reason I just prefer this approach, because it seems cleaner)

Recall that the tangent bundle $TX$ is the union of all tangent spaces equipped with an appropriate differentiable structure, that is $TX := \bigcup\limits_{x \in X}T_xX$. Now, we can define the **pushforward of $\psi$** to be the map $\psi_*: TX \to TN$ defined by
\begin{align}
\psi_*\big( [\gamma]\big) := [\psi \circ \gamma]
\end{align}

Now, for each $x \in X$, denote the restriction, $\psi_* \big|T_xX$, by the more convenient symbol $\psi_{*x}$. Therefore, $\psi_{*x}$ is a map with domain $T_xX$, but the codomain is the codomain of $\psi_*$, which is $TN$. So, we get the map $\psi_{*x} : T_xX \to TN$. But now, as an easy theorem, you can prove that the image of $\psi_{*x}$ lies entirely inside the tangent space $T_{\psi(x)}N$, therefore we can without much harm, restrict the codomain as well to get a map $\psi_{*x}: T_xX \to T_{\psi(x)}N$.

---

Now that hopefully the notation is clear, I think their equalities are really just due to sloppiness/laziness in notation (which is pretty common in this context). These are the more proper ways of stating the equalities: $(\text{id}_X)_* = \text{id}_{TX}$ and $(\text{id}_X)_{*x} = \text{id}_{T_xX}$.

Also, in the next line the notes have a typo, and it is written in slightly lazy notation. The more pedantic way of writing it is:

> Let $M,N,P$ be smooth manifolds, $\psi: M \to N$ and $\phi : N \to P$ be smooth maps. Then:
>   \begin{align}
> (\phi \circ \psi)_* = \phi_* \circ \psi_*
> \end{align}
>   (this is an equality of maps from $TM$ into $TP$)
>
> Also for every $x \in M$, we have
>   \begin{align}
> (\phi \circ \psi)_{*x} = \phi_{*\psi(x)} \circ \psi_{*x}
> \end{align}
>   (this is an equality of maps from $T_xM$ into $T_{(\phi \circ \psi)(x)}P$)

The first equation is really a true equality of functions in the sense that the domains, codomains and the rules of the functions on both sides all agree. In the second equation, I was careful to specify that "for all $x \in M\dots$", and you can check for yourself, that again, the domains and codomains all match up and all the compositions are well-defined.

Comment: Thanks again for a very detailed answer! It was the concept of a tangent bundle that I was missing to make my question more precise. So my intuition was correct that $\psi_*$ is trivially extended to the whole of $TX$. Also, that it was due to laziness or a typo that they omitted the$x$ in $(1_X)_{*x}$. One bit of notational confusion though: I usually see the tangent bundle defined as a *disjoint* union, so that it's not $[\gamma]$ that's an element of TX, but $(x, [\gamma])$. I suppose this wouldn't change much. (cont'd)

Comment: For part 1, we would extend to the bundle by defining $\psi_*(x, [\gamma]):=\psi_{*x}([\gamma])$. That would be even simpler, no?

Comment: @A_P people often talk about disjoint unions, and (to me atleast) their attempts to emphasise a point always just confused me even more. There is no difference between "union" and "disjoint union". A "disjoint union" of sets is still a union of sets. People only use the adjective "disjoint" to emphasize that the sets being unioned are inherently disjoint. Just take a look at the definition of tangent space. Fix two distinct points $x\neq y $ of the manifold $M$. Then, simply by definition, $T_xM$ and $T_yM$ are disjoint, because if there was a non-empty intersection [cont.]

Comment: then there would be an equivalence class of curves $[\gamma] \in T_xM \cap T_yM$. in other words, $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\gamma(0) = y$, but this is clearly a contradiction, because $x \neq y$. So, long story short, all the tangent spaces are disjoint simply by definition, so we can unambiguously define the tangent bundle $TM := \bigcup_{x \in M} T_xM$. So, we can unambiguously regard an element of $TM$ as an equivalnce class of curves $[\gamma]$. and now if you want to know which tangent space this curve belongs to, thats easy! $[\gamma]$ always lies in $ T_{\gamma(0)}M$ [cont.]

Comment: So, no, there is no need to consider elements of the tangent bundle as (point of manifold, equivalence class of curves) like $(x, [\gamma])$. It is enough to simply specify the curve; from this we can recover which tangent space it lies in (it lies in the tangent space at $\gamma(0)$). So, in the first case, we can simply say that $\psi_*([\gamma]) = \psi_{*\gamma(0)}([\gamma])$. Having said all this, some people do define the tangent bundle by explicitly writing the point down, so elements of $TM$ are $(x, [\gamma])$... what I ave just tried to convince you of is that this is unnecessary

Comment: Ah, I see. Most resources I've found for some reason decide to do it the $(x, [\gamma])$ way. The note in Wikipedia says "The disjoint union ensures that for any two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ of manifold $M$ the tangent spaces $T_1$ and $T_2$ have no common vector." So I guess there's a way of defining tangent spaces such that they're _not_ disjoint? This question gives a clue, though I'm not sure I've fully understood it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228840/is-the-tangent-bundle-the-disjoint-union-of-tangent-spaces

Comment: @A_P yes you're right, with certain definitions (I was slightly hasty in one of my earlier comments... I didn't consider other definitions of tangent space, and for a moment I forgot the set theoretic meaning of disjoint union) , like the one Lee provided, the the tangent spaces have non empty intersection, but with the definition of tangent space you're using (as equivalence class of curves) they're already disjoint, so there's no need at all to explicitly mention the point.